# Send ACF Frontend form Title through using publish_post in a multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, multisite

I'm trying to accomplish something that shouldn't be too difficult. However, I cannot get it right. The situation is as followed: I have a multisite with 2 subsites. All the 3 sites have their own custom post types.

I am trying to achieve the following: when a custom post type post is create on site ID = 3 using an ACF Frontend Form, this automatically creates another custom post type post on site with ID = 2.

Using the code below I am able to cross-post the posts from site A to site B. However now I only need to send the title through the Front-end form. The updated code can be found below:

```
add_action('publish_holiday', 'add_surf_holiday', 10, 2);
function add_surf_holiday($post) {

    switch_to_blog(2);
 
/* the rest of the function code */
  $labels = array(
      'post_title'            => $_POST['acf']['name_surf_accommodation'],
      'post_status'           => 'publish',
      'post_type'             => 'surf-holidays'
  );

wp_insert_post( $labels );

restore_current_blog();

}
```

Does any of you have an idea how to solve this issue?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Hope to hear from you soon!

Cheers,

Hans

Answer (score 0):

The issue maybe with where you have this code, and I'm making the assumption that you have placed it in functions.php and if so then you should remove it from there and then create a plugin with your code and Network Activate it.  Have you tried this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I transferred the code to a custom plugin, but unfortunately without any luck.